# Multiple VPNs with multiple virtual network gateways (Hub & Spoke)

Tags: azure, azure-networking, azure-vpn

I have a requirement to build out a networking solution that will have several site-to-site (S2S) VPNs and a point-2-site VPN (P2S). Ideally, we want each service provider/VPN to have its own set of infrastructure - dedicated Virtual Network Gateway as per the diagram:
[image]

I am unable to get traffic to flow to/from on-prem to spokes 4 & 5.

I have built some test VMs in various segments which can communicate. For example:

- Spoke 1 > hub > Spoke 4 + 5. ✅
- On-prem > Spoke 1 + 2 + 3. ✅

I can see from the logs that the UDRs are pushing traffic through the firewall.

If I understand the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/hybrid-networking/hub-spoke?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-network%2Ftoc.json&tabs=cli#spoke-connectivity) correctly I should be able to achieve this with the currently deployed infrastructure.

> If you require connectivity between spokes, consider deploying an Azure Firewall or other network virtual appliance.

All the examples I can find show the VNG in the hub network ([for example](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/hybrid-networking/hub-spoke?tabs=cli#architecture)) - which means it will be shared across service providers.

I also see other examples where there is a vnet-to-vnet VNG (VPN gateway) ([for example](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-troubleshoot-peering-issues#configure-virtual-network-peering-with-hub-spoke-topology-that-uses-on-premises-resources)) between the hub and spoke. Microsoft say:

> You can also use a VPN gateway to route traffic between spokes, although this choice will impact latency and throughput.

I am beginning to think the planned design is not possible. Must I have:

1. Shared VNG in the hub
2. vnet-to-vnet VNG in spokes and hub
3. 1 + 2
4. Design is possible, therefore route/firewall rules are wrong.

T.I.A

Comment: I have found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69578195/azure-multiple-s2s-vpn-gateways-with-hub-and-spoke-architecture, but the OPs architecture is slightly different.

Comment: I would suggest to use network watcher to do some troubleshooting: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-troubleshoot-overview. I don't see an inbound network flow to spoke 4 and 5, how did you have that setup? I only see a VNET peering. I also doubt that in a service provider scenario an vnet peering is a good solution, ideally you want to isolate you customers as much as possible.

Comment: @woter324 Did you get this to work? I'm looking into designing the same solution, was it doable without using VirtualWAN?